# Upload and Save File Image as Bytea Data Type in laravel Postgresql

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I want to save image file into database as **byte** data type. I use framework **laravel 8**.

```
public function store(Request $request){
   $this->validate($request, [
        'file' => 'required|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg'
    ]);

   $file = addslashes($request->file('file'));
   $image_file = pg_escape_bytea(file_get_contents($file));

   $file = new File;
   $file['member_id'] = $request->session()->get('id');
   $file['file'] = $image_file;
   $file->save();
}
```

The image file can already be stored in the database but when I download the image file from the database if the uploaded file has a **.jpeg** extension then the result is like this..

**result** : [**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POhY4.png)

And if the uploaded file has an extension other than **.jpeg** then the result will be like this..

**result** : [**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFkon.png)

How to fix this problem? I want the image file to still look good when downloaded.
Please help me...

Comment: Can you show view page code